# What is a general enough linear subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-analysis, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry

I am reading Pierre Deligne's paper La conjecture de Weil : I.

In this paper he takes a general enough  linear subspace $A$ of codimension $2$ of a projective space $\mathbb{P}$ (see page 290 in the french version) which translation in frech is "sous-espace linéaire de codimension $2$ assez général", so I am wondering how I should understand the adjetive "General enough"? Thank you  in advance for your help!

Comment: Set of all codimension two linear subspaces form a Grassmannian. General means a (non-empty) open subset of this Grassmannian.

Comment: To build off Mohan's comment: the way this sort of thing typically goes is that if you keep reading, the author will invoke various properties that this hyperplane section has as a result of being general enough. It is these properties that determine the particular open subset, which is otherwise not explicitly described.